# Is there a possibility to create a Histogram using Kusto Query Language?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I was checking the kusto documentation to check if I can create a histogram but I didn't seem to find anything related to histograms. Only barcharts and columncharts.

Is there a way to create a histogram in KQL or that is not possible ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/binfunction

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz Thank you. But how can I render the histogram on kusto explorer. What should the syntax be ?

Comment: See answer ....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can be done using [bin()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/binfunction)

```
// Generation of a data sample. Not part of the solution.
range i from 0 to 100 step 1 | project i, r = sqrt(-2*log(rand()))*sin(2*pi()*rand()) 
// Solution starts here.
| summarize count() by bin(r, 0.5)
| render columnchart
```

[image]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAy3KQQ6CMBAF0L2Jd/jLaYOmkLj0MKWMWENbnE4XGA4vJm5fnvg8MyIeUhIctKB3DlV5RY8dq5QXB0XsILijvkXpMtilzCQ%20T2SMsTVmGuwaydi/4XzaUVtKXuKHEUrLSgbjhvG40sFdb%20Z3hPPEcoSlpRyeXvQLBxE6E5AAAAA=)